# Script/regex for log file editing

Tags: python, regex, bash, perl, for-loop

I've been trying to write a code for handling the various log files I'm dealing with everyday. I tried writing with bash, perl and python but so far no so good..

Here is a sample of the log:

```
Table TRKGRP1: New table control.
      TRKGRP1: 1000 tuples checked. Tuple checking still in progress...
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TRKGRP1: tuples checked 1297, passed 1297, failed 0.
Table TOLLTRKS: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TOLLTRKS: tuples checked 3, passed 3, failed 1.
Table BRANDOPT: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl BRANDOPT: tuples checked 0, passed 0, failed 0.
Table C7UPTMR: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl C7UPTMR: tuples checked 4, passed 4, failed 3.
Table TOPSCOIN: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TOPSCOIN: tuples checked 0, passed 0, failed 2.
```

What I need is the part of the text from "Table" to "failed 1/2/3" I only need to capture the parts that end with failed 1, failed 2 and failed 3. failed 0 is not needed. Keep in mind that these logs sometimes come longer or shorter, not always 3 lines.

Here is the expected output:

```
Table TOLLTRKS: New table control.
Completed tuple checking.
SUMMARY: Tbl TOLLTRKS: tuples checked 3, passed 3, failed 1.  
Table C7UPTMR: New table control.
Completed tuple checking.
SUMMARY: Tbl C7UPTMR: tuples checked 4, passed 4, failed 3.  
Table TOPSCOIN: New table control.
Completed tuple checking.
SUMMARY: Tbl TOPSCOIN: tuples checked 0, passed 0, failed 2.
```

I would really appreciate it if you guys could give me a hand.

Comment: I'm sorry but don't have all of my tryouts with me. Most of them are left at office. For example here is one I tried with php

Comment: $re = "/^Table.*$(\\n\\s.*(failed\\s1\\.$){0,1})*/m"; 

preg_match_all($re,$st,$out);

print_r($out);

?>

Comment: @Cyrus ok mate, done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python-- this isn't the most efficient, but hopefully the algorithm is clear, and it works:

```
text = '''
Table TRKGRP1: New table control.
      TRKGRP1: 1000 tuples checked. Tuple checking still in progress...
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TRKGRP1: tuples checked 1297, passed 1297, failed 0.
Table TOLLTRKS: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TOLLTRKS: tuples checked 3, passed 3, failed 1.
Table BRANDOPT: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl BRANDOPT: tuples checked 0, passed 0, failed 0.
Table C7UPTMR: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl C7UPTMR: tuples checked 4, passed 4, failed 3.
Table TOPSCOIN: New table control.
      Completed tuple checking.
      SUMMARY: Tbl TOPSCOIN: tuples checked 0, passed 0, failed 2.
'''
lines = text.split('\n')
```

or, from a file

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

then

```
f = open("output.txt", 'w')
buf = []
show = False
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('Table'):
        if show:
            f.writelines(buf)
        buf = []
        show = True
    buf.append(line)
    if line.find('failed 0') >= 0:
        show = False
if show:
    f.writelines(buf)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help! One last question. How can I edit this code in order to point a file to search from and forward my output to a different file?

Comment: @OkanAkca: edited for file I/O

Answer (score 1):

Break the file into groups of lines, then it becomes trivial to extract the data you want from the group. The following shows how to break the file into the groups you want.

When you have the whole file in one variable:

```
while ($file =~ /\G ( \S[^\n]*\n (?:(?:[^\n\S][^\n]*)?\n)* )/xg) {
   process($1);
}
```

When reading a line at a time:

```
my $buf;
while (<>) {
   if (/^\S/) {
      process($buf) if length($buf);
      $buf = '';
   }

   $buf .= $_;
}

process($buf) if length($buf);
```

`process` is quite trivial.

```
sub process {
   for ($_[0]) {
      print
         if /^Table /
         && /, failed (\d+)\.$/m
         && $1 > 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried executing first part of your code by saving it is a perl file but having syntax error when I try it.  

`./test.pl < logfile `  
`./test.pl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `(' `

Comment: Looks like you try to execute your Perl script using your shell. (That message doesn't come from Perl.) Do you have a proper shebang line?